# Printing "#include" or the Whole File if not Found Linux Command Line

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to figure out how to search a file for example test.txt for "#include" and print the first instance of it that is found. However if it is not found I want to print out the whole file. I can do the first part with grep "#include" test.txt | head -n 1 but can't seem to figure out how to include the second requirement.

Comment: Try cat command or echo

Comment: I don't seem to follow, could you give an example?

Comment: @jhon, look, glenn jackman's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -m 1 '#include' "$file" || cat "$file"
```

You can control grep's output in many ways with grep options.
grep exits non-success status if the match is not found.

Comment: Ah I see. As a follow up, what would I do if I wanted to check if the file contains at 2 "#includes" and otherwise print the whole file.

Comment: I assume you meant to write "at *least* 2" -- `count=$( grep -m 2 -c patt file ); if (( count < 2 )); then cat file; fi`

Comment: How would I do it it if I wanted to do it in one line without semi colons?

Comment: Why is that important?